# Using REGEXREPLACE to insert commas into values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, number-formatting, regexp-replace

How do I go about using REGEXREPLACE to insert commas into values in Google Sheets? Example:

cell A1 = `1234567890`

expected output in B1 = `1,234,567,890`

edit:
The intention would be so that the user would not need to format anything themselves. This issue is from a template I'm doing up, sample sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n-KXqcSpx_DpvrOv9A4UsKn1amGGEUCpyzWWDphWdJY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXT(A1; "#,###,###,##0")
```

Comment: Thanks man! Glad to know this was possible without REGEXREPLACE.

Comment: Any idea on how to incorporate this TEXT() with QUERY()?

Comment: @qazamy QUERY has its own formatting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdEak.png see: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: I can't seem to be able to incorporate it in. Sorry for the trouble. Perhaps you can give it try with this sample sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n-KXqcSpx_DpvrOv9A4UsKn1amGGEUCpyzWWDphWdJY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @qazamy proper syntax would be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGhfU.png however query is known to be buggy when it comes to mixing text values with numeric values like in your case so try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qqUg.png

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=A1
```

and change the format to

```
#,##0
```

Comment: This wouldn't be an option as the intention would be so that the user would not need to format anything themselves. This issue is from a template I'm doing up, sample sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n-KXqcSpx_DpvrOv9A4UsKn1amGGEUCpyzWWDphWdJY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

To insert commas into values in Google Sheets, I recommend:

- Select the range of cells you'd like to format or modify.
- Click Format and then Number.
- Select the format to apply to the range of cells.

Comment: This wouldn't be an option as the intention would be so that the user would not need to format anything themselves. This issue is from a template I'm doing up, sample sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n-KXqcSpx_DpvrOv9A4UsKn1amGGEUCpyzWWDphWdJY/edit?usp=sharing